# Extract bit depth from wav file using wavfile.read

Tags: python, wav, bit-depth

I was attempting to read the bit-depth from a wav file using `wavfile.read`, however, I have not been successful.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, rfft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import librosa
import librosa.display

input_file = (r'G:/pt5GAL_TCL_mono_Mono.wav')
sample_rate1, samples = wavfile.read(input_file)

# File Info
signal, sample_rate2 = librosa.load(input_file)
print('Total number of samples: ', signal.shape[0])
print('Sample rate: ', sample_rate1)
print('Length of file in seconds: ', librosa.get_duration(signal))
# print('Bit Depth: ', bits_per_sample)
```

How I can return the bit depth of the wav file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly access the number of bits per sample from the return value of `scipy.io.wavfile.read`, but you can determine it indirectly (and possibly ambiguously) from the dtype of the returned NumPy array according to the table shown in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html.

Of course, you could just use the `wave` module from the Python standard library which has a method [`getsampwidth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getsampwidth).